# How to update the state in in react js

Tags: reactjs

am new to react. I want to update status of the user in the below code. I know this is not the right way to update a record Can anyone please help me, which is the best way to update the record. Thanks in advance.

Here I want to change the status of the user when he changes the status.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Badge, Card, CardBody, CardHeader, Col, Row, Table } from 'reactstrap';
import axios from '../../global/config'
import { AppSwitch } from '@coreui/react';

function UserRow(props) {
  const user = props.user
  const userStatus = user.status ? "Active" : "Inactive";
  function ChnageUserStatus(){   
    axios.delete('..some api end point..'+props.user._id,{
      data: { "status": !user.status }
      })
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.data);       
          //.. something is missing here
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
  })  
   }
  return (    
    <tr key={user.id}>  
      <td>{userStatus}</td>
      <td><AppSwitch id="status" name="status" checked={user.status ? true : false} className={'mx-1'} variant={'pill'} color={'primary'} onChange={ChnageUserStatus} /> </td>
    </tr>
  )
}

class Users extends Component {

  state = {
    usersInfo: []
}
  componentDidMount() {
  
    axios.get('...api end point here...')
      .then(response => {
        const users = response.data.data;        
        this.setState( { usersInfo: users } );      
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      }); 
  }

  render() {       
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
       
                <Table responsive hover>
                  <thead>
                    <tr>                      
                      <th scope="col">Status</th>
                      <th scope="col">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>                   
                    {this.state.usersInfo.map((user2, index) =>
                      <UserRow key={index} user={user2} />
                    )}
                  </tbody>
                </Table>  
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Users;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `UserRow` component is what's known as a *functional component* whereas your `Users` component is what's known as a *class component*. Functional components do not have a local state, as described within React's [State and Lifecycle documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

If you want to be able to make use of state within your `UserRow` component, you'll need to [convert it to a class component](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#converting-a-function-to-a-class) first.

If you want to directly modify the state of the `Users` component, you'll instead want to [pass a callback function through](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) into your `UserRow` component, but this may have some unexpected side effects.